# Git: Create remote branch to point another repository

Tags: git, githooks

I have a repository which is actually a forked repository of some external repository. And I would like to create a remote branch named `upstream` which points to this external repository so that I can update every content of the external repository on the branch upstream.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a bunch of info on how to do that through Github

https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo

If you scroll down it tells you about setting your upstream, I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Linking to an external site is not an answer, especially as that site may disappear any time. We want to have it here, at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

let me put in Github context.

I fork a project `myself/myforkproject` (your project) from `origin/project` (some popular project in github)

to get this fork project in your local machine do a clone

1. `git clone https://github.com/yourusername/your-forked-project.git`
2. You can now create a new branch `git branch myupstream-branch`  in
   your local machine
3. do a `git remote -v` just to check what is pointing to
   `origin/project` and `myself/myforkproject`

> upstream https://github.com/yourusername/your-forked-project.git
>   origin https://github.com/popular-project-creator/popular_project.git

1. now you first do `git checkout myupstream-branch`
2. after this do `git pull origin master` this will do fetch + merge
   now at this point your local machine `myupstream-branch` branch as latest code from     `origin/master` branch

if you want to push this to github

`git push upstream myupstream-branch`  here upstream is pointing to your github forked project   `git remote -v`